# Range parameters only effecting row 2 and 3? Need to effect any row in the sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using this script to send an e-mail to the recipient in column H with the body being column C. I have a problem with it only working with rows 2 and 3 and no other rows below. I've tried tweaking things but can't seem to figure out the glitch. Help would be appreciated. I can post a sample sheet but with the problem being simply the range and not the functionality itself, I figured it's not necessary.

```
function emailService(e) {
  var source = e.source;
  var sheet = source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;
  var row = range.getRow();
  var column =range.getColumn();
  console.log("column::", column);

  var targetRange = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 9)
  var targetValues = targetRange.getValues();
  console.log("targetRange:: ", targetValues);
  var body = targetValues[0][2];
  var recipient = targetValues[0][7];
  var checkboxValue = targetValues[0][8];
  var subject = "Detail Request Completed"

  if(column = 9 && checkboxValue == true) {
    console.log("checkbox marked true")

    GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);
  } else if (column = 9 && checkboxValue == false) {
    console.log("checkbox marked false")
  } else {
    console.log("hey hey")
  }
}
```

Comment: First of all, is this an onEdit trigger? Secondly, shouldn't `column = 9` be `column == 9` and lastly since checkboxValues is boolean it could be simply `&& checkboxValue` not `&& checkboxValue == true`.  Fix these and lets see what happens.

Comment: I changed both and it did not work. After keeping `&& checkboxValue == true`  as it was and changing `column = 9` to `column == 9` as suggested it works like a charm. Thank you

Comment: @TheWizEd, can you kindly post your comment as answer so it can be known as the solution and be upvoted/accepted? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try revising your code as shown below:

```
if(column == 9 && checkboxValue == true) {
   console.log("checkbox marked true")

   GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);
} else if(column == 9 && checkboxValue == false) {
   console.log("checkbox marked false")
} else {
   console.log("hey hey")
}
```